# Create tables in database from queries in a text file

Tags: php, mysql, text-files

I have the following PHP page to create a table using a text file.

> **table_create.php**

```
<?php
include $db;
$query_file = "sql.txt";

$fp    = fopen($query_file, 'r');
$sql = fread($fp, filesize($query_file));
fclose($fp); 

$retval = mysql_query($sql);
if(! $retval )
{
  die("Could not create the tables<br>");
}
echo "Table created successfully<br>";
?>
```

> **sql.txt**

```
CREATE TABLE ht_account (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  date date NOT NULL,
  type varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  mode varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  party varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  payee varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  rate decimal(13,2) NOT NULL,
  box int(11) NOT NULL,
  amount decimal(13,2) NOT NULL,
  token varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  remarks varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  user varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  user_confirm varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  status varchar(50) NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE ht_bank (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  ac_no varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  address varchar(50) NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE ht_user_role (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  value varchar(50) NOT NULL);
```

When I try to create a single table in the sql.txt file, the code works perfectly.
For example:

```
CREATE TABLE ht_account (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  date date NOT NULL,
  type varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  mode varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  party varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  payee varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  rate decimal(13,2) NOT NULL,
  box int(11) NOT NULL,
  amount decimal(13,2) NOT NULL,
  token varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  remarks varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  user varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  user_confirm varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  status varchar(50) NOT NULL);
```

But when I try to create multiple tables, It does not create any table. I doubt that the format in the sql.txt may be incorrect.

Comment: I'm editing your code. You need to remove ";" after `address`, right here:

`ac_no varchar(50) NOT NULL, address varchar(50) NOT NULL), user_role varchar(50) NOT NULL);`, and replace with ","

Answer (score 2):

The format is, almost sure, correct but mysql_query doesn't work with multiple queries:

> mysql_query() sends a unique query (multiple queries are not
>   supported) to the currently active database on the server that's
>   associated with the specified link_identifier.

It's better to use mysqli functions because mysql ones are deprecated for PHP 5.5 and mysqli has the function mysqli_multi_query that you need.

If you still want to use mysql functions you could do something like:

```
$sql_array=explode(';',$sql);
foreach ($sql_array as $s) {
   if(! mysql_query($s)){
      echo mysql_error()."<br>";
   }
}
```

Comment: I created the file using this tutorial

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/create_mysql_database_using_php.htm

Comment: I see the same error in the tutorial. They said there: "its better to create a text file first and put all the SQL commands in that text file and then load that file into $sql variable and excute those commands" but as I copy from php.net, mysql_query only works with unique queries

Comment: May be was misguided with that tutorial. Or do you know how to import table using a .sql file?

Comment: If you are in linux the easiest way is use command line: mysql -uUSER -pPASSWORD DATABASE < FILE.sql

Comment: No , I using it in the 'localhost' with XAMPP. I need to execute this only through PHP

Comment: I've edited my answer to see the error. Please confirm if its a PHP error or SQL error.